# Remove Element Description In Controller (Zend_Form)

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I would like to edit an element description in the action controller. I'm trying to do it like this:

```
$form->element->setAttrib('description', '');
```

But it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define your own form element decorators, omitting the description decorator. Check this [tutorial](http://devzone.zend.com/article/3450) for details.

Comment: Thanks. I know about decorators. What I needed to do is to have the decorators include the description attribute but remove the description in controller based on data from the request object. I have figured out how to do it already (I used $form->element->removeDecorator('description'); in the action controller).

Answer (score 1):

To actually remove the description data, rather than the description decorator, you can use:

```
$form->getElement('elementName')->setDescription('');
```

Comment: Well, that's what I did (see my OP - it's just an alternative using magic __get()) and it didn't work. I had to remove the decorator to get rid of the description.

Comment: Oh. Well, I have no good answer for that I'm afraid, other than it works for me (ZF 1.9).